# Rails partial locals not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got

```
Class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :answers
end
```

and

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :question
end
```

My index action of question list all the questions and the basic CRUD actions.

```
<% @questions.each do |question| %>
```

And inside this loop I have another to show all answers to that question

```
<% question.answers.each do |answer| %>
```

After the action buttons I rendered the answer form partial

```
<%= render partial: 'answers/form' , question_id: question.id%>
```

But when them partial is rendered the `question_id` to the answer is aways 1.

I also tried

```
<%= render partial: 'answers/form', :locals => {:question_id => question.id} %>
```

Still no success.
This is the full index and form codes.
https://gist.github.com/CassioGodinho/7412866
(Please ignore the data-toggle on the Index, its also not working yet)

Comment: Why don't you just pass a new answer record to the partial, then the `question_id` should be clear to the partial. Something like `render partial: 'answers/form', locals: { :@answer => question.answer.build }`? (Maybe `:@answer` doesn't work, then you need to try a few more options like `:"@answer"`).

Comment: Oh god, I feel stupid now. This worked fine, just had to change to `question.answers.build`

Comment: just a quick shot in the dark, try `:question_id => question.id.to_s` ? Anytime I use id Rails always throws a fit about converting Fixnum to String but not sure if it would do the same in this scenario. If you're not getting that error then it's probably fine. __EDIT__: just saw that you've fixed it so just ignore this....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not a good practice to pass new instance variable as local to a partial
you can build the answer and then pass it as locals

```
<%= render partial: 'answers/form', :locals => {:answer => question.answers.build} %>
```

and in partial

```
<div class="answer_form">
<%= form_for(answer) do |f| %>
<% if answer.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(answer.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this answer from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% answer.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :content %><br>
<%= f.text_area :content %>
</div>
<div>
<%= f.label :question %>
<%= f.collection_select(:question_id, @questions, :id, :title) %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As Thomas Klemm showed it was easier to pass the @answer to the partial.

```
<%= render partial: 'answers/form', :locals => {:@answer => question.answers.build} %>
```